# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'size')

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have 2 arrays. I'm using a for loop on arr1 and checking if arr2 contains some of the same shoe sizes as in arr1. If the condition checks that a shoe size from arr1 does not exist in arr2, then it will push an object (`{size: '-'}`) to the newArr, if it does exist it will just push the shoe object from arr2 into newArr

code:

```js
const newArr = []
    const arr1 = [
        { size: 'US 3' },
        { size: 'US 4' },
        { size: 'US 5' },
        { size: 'US 6' },
        { size: 'US 7' },
        { size: 'US 8' },
        { size: 'US 9' },
        { size: 'US 10' },
        { size: 'US 11' },
        { size: 'US 12' },
        { size: 'US 13' },
        { size: 'US 14' },
        { size: 'US 15' },
        { size: 'US 16' }
    ]
    const arr2 = [
        { size: '4', cost: '170' },
        { size: '6', cost: '75' },
        { size: '7', cost: '75' },
        { size: '8', cost: '78' },
        { size: '9', cost: '80' },
        { size: '10', cost: '85' },
        { size: '11', cost: '73' },
        { size: '12', cost: '77' },
        { size: '14', cost: '100' }
    ]

     for (const arr1Item in arr1) {
         let arr1Size = arr1[arr1Item].size
         let includes = arr1Size.includes(arr2[arr1Item].size);
    
         if(includes) {
           newArr.push(arr2[arr1Item])
         } else {
           newArr.push({size: '-'})
         }
      }
 
 console.log(newArr)
```

The problem is whenever I run this I get this error: `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'size')`

This error is happening because of this code here:

> arr2[arr1Item].size

The thing I'm confused about is if I `console.log(arr2[arr1Item])` INSIDE the for loop, it returns each object from arr2 with no error, only gives an error when I add `.size`.

I've been stuck on this for a bit, would appreciate any help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You iterate over `arr1` using the index variable `arr1Item`, but then use that to index into `arr2`.  As `arr1` has more elements than `arr2`, you end up trying to access`arr2[9] === undefined` and `undefined` does not have a size attribute hence the error `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'size')`.

**Couple of other problems**

1. newArr is not a const.
2. `Array.protoype.includes()` is used to see if, say, `4` of `arr2.size` matches `arr.size` like `US 4` but this will also incorrectly (substring) match `US 14`.

**Potential solution**

Using the fact that both `arr1` & `arr2` are sorted by the (normalized) `size` attribute, and that the set of (normalized) `arr2.size` is a subset of (normalized) `arr1.size` you can do the transformation in linear time (`O(arr1.length)`):

```js
const arr1 = [
    { size: 'US 3' },
    { size: 'US 4' },
    { size: 'US 5' },
    { size: 'US 6' },
    { size: 'US 7' },
    { size: 'US 8' },
    { size: 'US 9' },
    { size: 'US 10' },
    { size: 'US 11' },
    { size: 'US 12' },
    { size: 'US 13' },
    { size: 'US 14' },
    { size: 'US 15' },
    { size: 'US 16' }
]
const arr2 = [
    { size: '4', cost: '170' },
    { size: '6', cost: '75' },
    { size: '7', cost: '75' },
    { size: '8', cost: '78' },
    { size: '9', cost: '80' },
    { size: '10', cost: '85' },
    { size: '11', cost: '73' },
    { size: '12', cost: '77' },
    { size: '14', cost: '100' }
]

let newArr = []
for(let i1 = 0, i2 = 0; i1 < arr1.length; i1++) {
        if(i2 < arr2.length && arr1[i1].size.substr(3) === arr2[i2].size) {
                newArr.push(arr2[i2]);
                i2++;
        } else {
                newArr.push({size: '-'});
        }
}
console.log(newArr)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use filter for matches.

```js
let newArr = []
const arr1 = [
  { size: 'US 3' },
  { size: 'US 4' },
  { size: 'US 5' },
  { size: 'US 6' },
  { size: 'US 7' },
  { size: 'US 8' },
  { size: 'US 9' },
  { size: 'US 10' },
  { size: 'US 11' },
  { size: 'US 12' },
  { size: 'US 13' },
  { size: 'US 14' },
  { size: 'US 15' },
  { size: 'US 16' }
]
const arr2 = [
  { size: 'US 4', cost: '170' },
  { size: '6', cost: '75' },
  { size: '7', cost: '75' },
  { size: '8', cost: '78' },
  { size: '9', cost: '80' },
  { size: '10', cost: '85' },
  { size: '11', cost: '73' },
  { size: '12', cost: '77' },
  { size: '14', cost: '100' }
]
  
arr1.forEach(a1Item => {
  let foundItems = arr2.filter(a2Item => a2Item.size === a1Item.size);
  // OR PARTIAL MATCH (arr1.size '4' would match arr2.size 'US 4')
  // let foundItems = arr2.filter(a2Item => a2Item.size.includes(a1Item.size));

  if (foundItems.length > 0) {
    foundItems.forEach(fItem => {
      newArr.push(fItem);
    });
  } else {
    // ADDED COST TO KEEP ITEMS CONSISTENT
    newArr.push({size: '-', cost: '-'});
  }
});

console.log(newArr);
```

Comment: Good job!  Even the first solution you had was good, and this revised solution has output that might be even more useful than what op asked for.   Suggest removing the output comments as Run code snippet will generate it on demand.